# SignalR needs to target specific games with Game ID and not all live games

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-2

I didnt think about this but this code is sending the game model to all clients.  I need to use the GameID from this controller action and only target the clients watching that game.  How do I do that?

**Publish Controller Action**

```
public UpdateGameResponse UpdateGame(int gameId)
        {

...

 var model = Game.Create(XDocument.Load(httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream)).Parse();


         GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameCastHub>().Clients.All.receiveUpdates(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));

}
```

**Hub**

```
 [HubName("gamecastHub")]
    public class GameCastHub : Hub
    {
    }
```

**Client**

```
  var connected = false;
                var gamecastHub = $.connection.gamecastHub;

                if (gamecastHub) {

                    gamecastHub.client.receiveUpdates = function (updates) {
                        console.log('New updates received');
                        processUpdates(updates);
                    };

                    connectLiveUpdates();

                    $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
                        console.log('Live updates connection running slow');
                    });

                    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
                        connected = false;
                        console.log('Live updates disconnected');
                        setTimeout(connectLiveUpdates, 10000);
                    });

                    $.connection.hub.reconnecting(function () {
                        console.log('Live updates reconnecting...');
                    });

                    $.connection.hub.reconnected(function () {
                        connected = false;
                        console.log('Live updates reconnected');
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using either the connection Id associated with each connection to the hub or creating groups. 
Note: Each GameID must have its own connection to the hub in order to use the connection Id solution.

I prefer to use groups from personal experience but either way can be done.

**To create a group in the hub you will need to create a method in your hub class.**

```
public async void setGroup(string groupName){
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

Secondly, you will need a JS function on the client side to call the hub function.

```
$.connection.hub.invoke("setGroup", groupName).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

In your case, you can place your gameID as the `groupname` and then call `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameCastHub>().Clients.Groups(gameID).receiveUpdates(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));`

**To retrieve the connection Id:**

```
var _connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
```

Then send the connection Id to the server,
and proceed to using the call `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameCastHub>().Clients.Clients.Client(_connectionId).receiveUpdates(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));` to call that specific connection.